# Check a todos mis input the tpye checkbox con una clase

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy generando una tabla donde tengo un checkbox para pasar lista y me gustaria añadir un botton que al hacerle click se seleccionen todos los check con esa clase.
Ahora mismo mi funcion es esta pero no me los marca.
Y al igual que los marca, que tambien pueda deseleccionarlo.

```
$("#marcar").click(function() {
      $('.checklista').each(function() { 
          $(this).prop("checked");
      });
});
```

Lo que espero que suceda es que si esta marcado siga marcado y se marquen los demás y para quitar todos igual que si ya este sin marcar siga sin marcar.

Y los input checkbox estan dentro de una tabla uno por cada fila.

Mis input son así

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checklista" />
```

Cuando hago click si que recorre el each de cada uno pero al asignarle el checked no me los esta marcando.

Comment: Podrías describir mejor que si hace este código al momento así como agregar tu HTML por favor

Comment: También estaría bien que explicases que esperas que suceda si al momento de darle el botón para marcar existe ya algún check marcado. ¿Se marcarían los que faltan por marcar? ¿Se marcarían los desmarcados y se marcarían los marcados? En el caso primero, ¿cuándo se considera que el botón ha de desmarcar y no marcar? ¿Cuándo existen más check marcados que desmarcados o actúa la primera vez que lo clickas marcando y la segunda desmarcando y así sucesivamente? Cuanta más información des al respecto y cuanto más mascado tengas el problema mejor se te podrá ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que pides esta todo correcto. Lo único que debes cambiar es:

```
$(this).prop("checked");
```

**por**

```
$(this).attr("checked");
```